# JavaScript - Create and Pass Multiple Amount of Unknown Arguments from a String to a Function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, url-routing, window.location

I'm in the process of creating a JavaScript class that handles routing/hashing.

I'm wondering if there's a way to split the **window.location.hash** string into a set of arguments to pass to another function.

Example hash:

```
var hash = "#some/place?id=42&&name=Brian";
```

I can, of course, split the string and get the arguments and their values, but how would I go about passing these to a function, similar to (given the previous hash) calling:

```
// ID, NAME
someFunction(42, "Brian");
```

We must take into account that we don't know the exact number of arguments we'll be dealing with. All we do know is that the arguments in the hash are in the same order as the function expects; eg: given the previous example, our function would receive: ID first, then NAME, then any other arguments we're passing.

So...

```
var hash = "#some/place?id=42&&name=Brian";

// ID, NAME
someFunction(42, "Brian");
```

Or...

```
var hash = "#some/place?id=42&&age=33&&name=Brian";

// ID, AGE, NAME
someFunction(42, 33, "Brian");
```

etc...

Comment: are you asking how to extract the parameters from the querystring or how to call someFunction with an unknown number of parameters?

Comment: as far as passing unknown amount of parameters, I would create an array and pass that, then you can loop through it in your function.  Maybe an array of objects `[{id: 42}, {age: 33}, {name: 'brian'}]`

Comment: You could do that, but you should also check out Function.prototype.apply(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: @IrkenInvader That's one way I was thinking of heading, but it's not the end result I require. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Function.prototype.apply() method to supply a function with a list of arguments.  The first argument sets sets the "this" binding for the function, so for functions that do not operate within the scope of an object, you can pass null as the first argument.

```
var hash = "#some/place?id=42&&age=33&&name=Brian";

var getParams = function(hash){

  var parameters = [ ["id=","&&age"],["age=","&&name"],["name=",null] ];

  return parameters.map(function(p){

    var re1 = new RegExp(p[0]);
    var re2 = p[1]? new RegExp(p[1]): null;

    var start = hash.match(re1)['index'] + p[0].length;
    var end = re2 ? hash.match(re2)["index"]: hash.length;

    return hash.slice(start,end);

  })

};

function interpreter(id,age,name,kwargs){
  console.log( "id: "+id + " age: "+ age+ " name: "+name+ " kwargs: "+ kwargs );
}

interpreter.apply( null, getParams(hash) ) ;
```

Comment: Using the Function.prototype.apply() method and passing the array of arguments worked for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the arguments in a function like this :

```
var x = function(){

x = arguments&&arguments[0];
y= arguments&&arguments[1];
console.log(x+y);

};
x(3,4);
7
```

Comment: Hi,

The drawback of this is the called function should not need to iterate through arguments, ei: it should expect:

function someFun(param1, param2, ...) {}

The called function expects a certain amount of arguments, but we don't know how many we need to give, if this makes sense?

Essentially, we can give an uncertain amount of arguments to a function, but the function expects a certain amount. Also, the function should work like:

// param1 = "Dave", param2 = "Davidson"
someFunc(param1, param2, ...) {
    return param1 + param2;
}

... as if we're passing arguments as normal.